# NodeJS StreamReader reads even file is deleted

Tags: node.js, error-handling, stream

I implemented big-text file reading using `createReadStream`. In my implementation i wanted to test for error handling.

So i started process and renamed file, still entire file was read and all data were printed on console. In second try i did same but this time i deleted the file, and results were same, entire file was read and printed on console.

In short, I am reading a file using `createReadStream`, and after reading started even if i rename/delete the file, it still reads till the end.

Here is a sample implementation,

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readableStream = fs.createReadStream('mySampleTextFile.txt');

readableStream.on('data', (chunk) => console.log(chunk));
readableStream.on('end', () => console.log('Read till end !'));
```

`mySampleTextFile.txt` contains 600k rows with just number on each line, and i verified the last number logged to be exactly same as in the original file.
I am deleting the file before execution ends, i have two terminals open and in one i start execution and in second i fire delete/rename command.
I tried also deleting permanently means directly delete, not in trash.

Am i missing some fundamental of Stream or something? Please help me on this, it's not breaking anything but why it is not breaking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least on Unix-type OS'es, when you remove a file while it's open, the process that opened the file can still read from it (or write to it).

Removing such a file merely removes its directory entry so you can't see it anymore when running `ls` or a file browser, but the disk space it takes up won't be marked "available" until there are no more processes that are referencing the file (i.e. have it open).

What you could try is truncating the file instead of removing it:

```
cp /dev/null mySampleTextFile.txt
```

Comment: I am running Mac, means Unix based, so must be this the reason. Will do try and let you know. Thanks for quick answer.

Comment: I tried, it till doesn't emits an error but ends the reading. That's obvious as we are truncating file means the stream is not getting any more data from the file, thus the end.

Comment: @ErrHunter I was hoping that truncating would mess up the file pointer and thus throwing an error :-(

Comment: Got no errors `:/`. I understood the thing, so thanks !

Comment: Try changing permissions so it becomes unreadable for your uid (although, again, I'm not sure if this will actually do anything when the file has already been opened by your process).

Comment: Same, got no errors `:/` . Thanks for creative idea though.